# Hypersurface of singular plane cubics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, intersection-theory, enumerative-geometry

In the projective space $\mathbb{P}^9 = \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]_3)$, parametrizing plane cubics, consider the hypersurface $X\subset\mathbb{P}^9$ whose points corresponds to singular cubics. The degree of $X$ is $12$.

Let $SX\subset X$ be the singular locus of $X$. Are the dimension and the degree of $SX$ and the type of singularity of $X$ at a general point of $SX$ known?

Thanks.

Comment: This hypersurface is projective dual to the triple Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2$, hence the universal tangent hyperplane to the Veronese is its resolution of singularities. You can use this resolution to control singularities.

Comment: [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) is capable of computing [the equation of $X$](https://gist.github.com/Gro-Tsen/60b0dea2b7ff310c3a1fea08e302bdc6) (2040 terms), and the Hilbert polynomial of $SX$: the latter is found to be $23/1680\, t^7 - 11/40\, t^6 + 177/40\, t^5 - 107/3\, t^4 + 47681/240\, t^3 - 78727/120\, t^2 + 265207/210\, t - 1054$. So it has dimension $7$ and degree $69$. I can post the code as an answer if that's of interest.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen. Yes please. It would be great to have the code. But are you sure about the degree being $69$? In this case a general plane section of $X$ would be an irreducible plane curve of degree $12$ with $69$ singular points, which is not possible.

Comment: @Mor Ah yes, I think the problem about the degree comes from the fact that I computed the singular locus with multiplicities (as defined by the Jacobian ideal), so maybe that's not very useful to you. But I posted the code as an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen. Thanks a lot. I am trying to compute the geometric genus of a general plane section of $X$ with Magma but it's taking forever. Do you think this can be done with Sage?

Comment: @Mor I think it can be done, but I don't know Sage well enough to do it, and I suspect it's going to take just as much forever as with Magma.

Comment: The singular locus of $X^*$ is not irreducible. It may have degree $69$ and it does not contradict the fact that a degree $12$ irreducible plane curve has at most $55$ singular points. Indeed, some components of $X^*_{sing}$ might well have dimension strictly less than $7$ and it that case, a general plane section would miss them.

Comment: @Mor Note that while you probably can't do anything with a *generic* plane section, you can probably do things with a *random* plane section if you can be content with a likely-but-not-proven result. I've updated my answer to explain why $SX$ appears to be made up of a degree $21$ component with multiplicity $1$ and a degree $24$ component with multiplicity $2$ (plus maybe lower-dimensional stuff, but I don't know how to see this).

Answer (score 7):

Let $X = v_3(\mathbb{P}^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^9$ be the third Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (given by the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(3)$). A hyperplane section of $X$ corresponds to the vanishing locus of section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(3)$, that is a plane cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$. The variety of singular hyperplane sections of $X$ is called the projective dual of $X$ and denoted by $X^* \subset \left(\mathbb{P}^9\right)^*$. It parametrizes the singular plane cubics. Its singular locus is not irreducible. A union of some of its components parametrizes plane cubics with (at least) a cusp and the union of the other parametrizes plane cubics with (at least) two singular points.

An easy count of dimension shows that both these schemes are hypersurfaces in $X^*$ (and in particular $X^*$ is not a normal hypersurface). On the other hand, given any smooth $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, there is a general theory studying the subschemes of $X^*$ which parametrize cuspidal and multinodal hyperplane sections. Using the Reflexivity Theorem in projective duality, you can show that, under favorable hypotheses, they are always hypersurfaces in $X^*$. [Holweck's Phd thesis](https://theses.hal.science/tel-00737441/document), and in particular chapter 2, is a good reference for this theory.

**Edit** : As Sasha suggests in his comment, the conormal space $\mathbb{P}(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1))$ is a resolution of singularities. Furthermore, since the fiber of the map $ \mathbb{P}(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1)) \longrightarrow X^*$ over $H$ is the scheme-theoretic singular locus of the curve corresponding to $H$, on can deduce that the fibers over generic points of $X^*_{cusp}$ and $X^{*}_{multinode}$ are respectively:
one fat point ($A_2$) and two simple points ($2A_1$). This suggests that all generic points in $X^*_{cusp}$ and $X^*_{multinode}$ have multiplicity $2$ in $X$. In particular, in order to compute the genus of a generic plane section of $X$, one just needs to compute the degree the reduced hypersurface components of $X^*$.

Answer (score 6):

As requested in the comments, this is Sage code to compute the equation of $X$ and the Hilbert polynomial of its singular locus; note that “singular locus” here means the scheme-theoretic one, i.e., the locus defined by the Jacobian ideal, which whatever multiplicity it happens to have:

```
R.<a300,a210,a120,a030,a201,a111,a021,a102,a012,a003,x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ,13)
# Generic cubic polynomial in x,y,z:
gencub = a300*x^3 + a210*x^2*y + a120*x*y^2 + a030*y^3 + a201*x^2*z + a111*x*y*z + a021*y^2*z + a102*x*z^2 + a012*y*z^2 + a003*z^3
# Singular locus of the generic cubic curve:
sing = R.ideal([diff(gencub,x), diff(gencub,y), diff(gencub,z)])
# Perform elimination of y and z to compute the equation of the locus of singular curves:
tmp = sing.elimination_ideal([y,z])
eqn = R(tmp.gens()[0]/x^4)
# eqn is a degree 12 polynomial with 2040 terms
# Running len(factor(eqn)) verifies that this is irreducible

# Remove variables x,y,z to properly compute the Hilbert polynomial:
R0.<a300,a210,a120,a030,a201,a111,a021,a102,a012,a003> = PolynomialRing(QQ,10)
cvt = dict([(R.gens()[i], R0.gens()[i] if i<10 else 0) for i in range(13)])
eqn0 = R0(eqn.subs(cvt))

# Singular locus, described as the ideal generated by partial differentials of eqn0:
ssing0 = R0.ideal([diff(eqn0,v) for v in R0.gens()])

# Return its Hilbert polynomial:
ssing0.hilbert_polynomial()
# -> this returns:
# 23/1680*t^7 - 11/40*t^6 + 177/40*t^5 - 107/3*t^4 + 47681/240*t^3 - 78727/120*t^2 + 265207/210*t - 1054
```

In principle, running `ssing0.primary_decomposition()` should return the primary decomposition of the singular locus, but I suspect this will just take forever, so I don't think we can brute-force our way further.

---

**Update** (2022-12-14): While I don't think we can use Sage (through brute force) to *prove* the irreducible decomposition of the singular locus, we can *guess* what its degrees are by reducing mod a random prime $p$ (so as to make computations manageable) and then intersecting $SX$ with $6$ random hyperplanes and projecting down to a plane curve: the following code (to be run after the above) does this:

```
# Find a sensible prime mod which to reduce:
# (Note: Sage can only work up to 2^29 here)
while True:
    p = ZZ(floor(2^28+random()*2^28))
    if is_prime(p) and len(factor(eqn0.change_ring(GF(p))))==1:
        break
F = GF(p)
RF.<a300,a210,a120,a030,a201,a111,a021,a102,a012,a003> = PolynomialRing(F,10)
eqnF = RF(eqn0.change_ring(F))  # The equation mod p
ssingF = RF.ideal([diff(eqnF,v) for v in RF.gens()])

# Take a bunch of random hyperplane sections to reduce the dimension down to 1:
hyperplanes = [sum(F.random_element()*v for v in RF.gens()) for i in range(6)]
# Take the intersection of the singular locus (mod p) with these hyperplanes:
hypisect = (ssingF + RF.ideal(hyperplanes))
# Project down to a plane curve (this takes a few minutes):
hypiproj = hypisect.elimination_ideal([a210,a120,a201,a111,a021,a102,a012])
# Check that we haven't lost any bits:
if not len(hypiproj.gens())==1 and hypiproj.gens()[0].degree()==69:
    raise Exception("we were unlucky: try again")
# Equation of the plane curve in question:
hypipol = hypiproj.gens()[0]
# Now factor it:
[(f.degree(),d) for (f,d) in factor(hypipol)]
# -> this returns:
# [(21, 1), (24, 2)]
```

∴ This suggests, but does not prove, that the degree $69$ singular locus $SX$ (of dimension $7$) decomposes as a degree $21$ component with multiplicity $1$ and a degree $24$ component with multiplicity $2$ (plus maybe some lower-dimensional components which we can't see that way).  It does prove, if I am not mistaken, that the $7$-dimensional components can't factor any *more* than what I've just said.

**Further update:** After taking some examples, I believe the degree $21$ component is the closure of the locus of curves with two distinct singular points, whereas the degree $24$ component is the locus of curves with a cusp.